# Split list of strings to list of lists including original strings in Python

Tags: python, string, list

This is similar to splitting a list of strings into a list of lists of strings, but I want a copy of the original string as an element of the list that came from it. The purpose is I want to parse out elements from a filename, but I want to retain the filename, so after I match the list using the words, the filename is readily available, so I can do something with it.

For example,

```
stringList = ["wordA1_wordA2_wordA3","wordB1_wordB2_wordB3"]
```

becomes

```
splitList = [["wordA1_wordA2_wordA3","wordA1","wordA2","wordA3"],
             ["wordB1_wordB2_wordB3","wordB1","wordB2","wordB3"]]
```

I'm trying to do it in a single command as a list comprehension

The closest I've gotten is:

```
splitList = [[item,item.split('_')] for item in stringList]
```

which yields:

```
splitList = [["wordA1_wordA2_wordA3",["wordA1","wordA2","wordA3"]],
             ["wordB1_wordB2_wordB3",["wordB1","wordB2","wordB3"]]
```

I could work with this, but is there a more elegant suggestion that I could learn from?

I've tried

```
splitList = [item.split('_') + item for item in stringList]
```

which complains about not concatenating a list to a str.

And

```
splitList = [item.split('_').append(item) for item in stringList]
```

which creates a list of 'None's.

Comment: what is the output you are expecting ?

Answer (score 2):

You can unpack the split list with `*`:

```
splitList=[[item,*item.split('_')] for item in stringList]
```

which gives you the wanted

```
splitList = [["wordA1_wordA2_wordA3","wordA1","wordA2","wordA3"],
           ["wordB1_wordB2_wordB3","wordB1","wordB2","wordB3"]]
```

You can also do something like:

```
splitList=[[item] + item.split('_') for item in stringList]
```

to deal with the concatenation of string and list. `[item]` simply creates a list with single item `item` and concatenates it with the split list.

Answer (score 1):

The reason `[item.split('_').append(item)...]` returns `None`'s is because `list.append` is an in-place modifier, and does not have a return value.

It might be a bit more advantageous to use a `dict` here, rather than a `list` of `lists`, since the filename can be your key, and the individual components can be your values:

```py
stringList = ["wordA1_wordA2_wordA3","wordB1_wordB2_wordB3"]

string_dict = {filename: filename.split("_") for filename in stringList}

# {'wordA1_wordA2_wordA3': ['wordA1', 'wordA2', 'wordA3'], 'wordB1_wordB2_wordB3': ['wordB1', 'wordB2', 'wordB3']}
```

However, if you need a list:

```py
processed_list = [[filename, *filename.split("_")] for filename in stringList]

# [['wordA1_wordA2_wordA3', 'wordA1', 'wordA2', 'wordA3'], ['wordB1_wordB2_wordB3', 'wordB1', 'wordB2', 'wordB3']]
```

Where `[filename, *filename.split("_")]` uses the `*` to unpack the resulting list from `str.split` into the current list